# jQuery: passing arguments into the animate method as properties

Tags: javascript, jquery

My problem with jQuery is that the animation doesn't work when I use an arguement `dir`, but when I flat out type `left` or `right` (exactly the same values that `dir` passes) it seems fine.

```
function update(dir) {
    $('#label').animate({
        dir: '200px'
    }, 'slow');
}
$('#goLeft').click(function() {
    update('left');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) in order to pass a variable as a property.

In this case, you would use `[dir]`:

```
function update(dir) {
    $('#label').animate({
        [dir]: '200px'
    }, 'slow');
}
```

Basic example:

```js
function update(dir) {
    $('#animate').animate({
        [dir]: '100px'
    }, 'slow');
}
$('#go-left').click(function() {
    update('left');
});
$('#go-down').click(function() {
    update('top');
});
```

```css
#animate { position: relative; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="go-left">Go left</button>
<button id="go-down">Go down</button>
<div id="animate">Animate me</div>
```